# Can't upload to BigQuery from Perl

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-client

I am trying to perform an upload to BigQuery from Perl with a sample schema and some sample data.  I ran into dead ends following the documentation they provide, and so now I'm trying to mimic what the `bq` command line client successfully does.

I am tracing what `bq` does by adding a debug `print (method, uri, headers, body)` to the `request` method in `httplib2`.  I am tracing what my Perl library is doing by doing a `Dumper` on the response, which also includes the `_request` that I sent.  The pattern in `bq` is that they `POST` to an upload URL, then get back a `location` to `PUT` data to.  The corresponding job is monitored with a series of `GET` requests, and finally they respond.

In Perl my `POST` succeeds, and my `GET` fails with `Invalid Upload Request` (but no hint why it is invalid).  I am trying to figure out what difference between the two could explain my failure.  But I can't find it.

Here are (with the access_token, IP addresses and project_id elided) the traces that I get.

For the `POST` the information from Python is:

```
(
    u'POST',
    u'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<project ID>/jobs?uploadType=resumable&alt=json',
    {
        'content-length': '442',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'user-agent': u'bq/2.0 google-api-python-client/1.0',
        'X-Upload-Content-Length': '84',
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': u'Bearer <access token>'
    },
    '{"configuration": {"load": {"sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON", "destinationTable": {"projectId": "<project id>", "tableId": "demo_api", "datasetId": "tmp_bt"}, "maxBadRecords": 0, "schema": {"fields": [{"type": "STRING", "mode": "required", "name": "demo_string"}, {"type": "INTEGER", "mode": "required", "name": "demo_integer"}]}}}, "jobReference": {"projectId": "<project id>", "jobId": "bqjob_r139e633b7e522cf7_0000014031d9fb49_1"}}'
)
```

The corresponding Perl gets an apparently successful response object (in which you can see the `_request`) of:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
    '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
    '_content' => '',
    '_rc' => '200',
    '_headers' => bless( {
        'connection' => 'close',
        'client-response-num' => 1,
        'location' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<project id>/jobs?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Ur0mdwmZpMot6ftkgj1IkqK0f7oPbZrXWQekUDHK_E2o2HKznJO6DK2xPYCB-nhUGrMrEJJ7z1Tz9Crnka9e5EYGP1lWQ',
        'date' => 'Tue, 06 Aug 2013 20:46:05 GMT',
        'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority',
        'client-ssl-cipher' => 'RC4-SHA',
        'client-peer' => '<some ip>:443',
        'content-length' => '0',
        'client-date' => 'Tue, 06 Aug 2013 20:46:05 GMT',
        'content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleapis.com',
        'server' => 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 24 2013 17:20:01 (1374711601)',
        'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
    }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
    '_msg' => 'OK',
    '_request' => bless( {
        '_content' => '{"configuration":{"load":{"maxBadRecords":0,"destinationTable":{"datasetId":"tmp_bt","tableId":"perl","projectId":<project id>},"sourceFormat":"NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON","schema":{"fields":[{"mode":"required","name":"demo_string","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"required","name":"demo_integer","type":"INTEGER"}]}}},"jobReference":{"projectId":<project id>,"jobId":"perlapi_1375821964"}}',
        '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<project id>/jobs?uploadType=resumable')}, 'URI::https' ),
        '_headers' => bless( {
            'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.05',
            'content-type' => 'application/json',
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            ':X-Upload-Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'content-length' => 379,
            ':X-Upload-Content-Length' => '84',
            'authorization' => 'Bearer <access token>'
        }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
        '_method' => 'POST',
        '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
    }, 'HTTP::Request' )
}, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

And then we have a `PUT`.  On the Python side we sent:

```
(
    'PUT',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<project id>/jobs?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&upload_id=AEnB2UpWMRCAOffqyR0d7zvGVtD-KWhrC9jGB-q_igecJgoyz_mIHgEFfs9cYoPxUwUxuflQScMzGxDsKKJ_CJPQq4Os-AkdZA',
     {
         'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-83/84',
         'Content-Length': '84',
         'Authorization': u'Bearer <access token>',
         'user-agent': u'bq/2.0'
    },
    <apiclient.http._StreamSlice object at 0x10ce11150>
)
```

(I have verified that the stream slice object has the same 84 bytes as Perl.)  And here is the Perl failure:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
    '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
    '_content' => '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Invalid Upload Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Upload Request"
 }
}
',
    '_rc' => '400',
    '_headers' => bless( {
        'connection' => 'close',
        'client-response-num' => 1,
        'date' => 'Tue, 06 Aug 2013 20:46:07 GMT',
        'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority',
        'client-ssl-cipher' => 'RC4-SHA',
        'client-peer' => '<some IP address>:443',
        'content-length' => '193',
        'client-date' => 'Tue, 06 Aug 2013 20:46:07 GMT',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleapis.com',
        'server' => 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 24 2013 17:20:01 (1374711601)',
        'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
    }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
    '_msg' => 'Bad Request',
    '_request' => bless( {
        '_content' => '{"demo_string":"foo", "demo_integer":"2"}
{"demo_string":"bar", "demo_integer":"3"}
',
        '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/<project id>/jobs?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Ur0mdwmZpMot6ftkgj1IkqK0f7oPbZrXWQekUDHK_E2o2HKznJO6DK2xPYCB-nhUGrMrEJJ7z1Tz9Crnka9e5EYGP1lWQ')}, 'URI::https' ),
        '_headers' => bless( {
            'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.05',
            ':Content-Length' => '84',
            ':Content-Range' => '0-83/84',
            'content-length' => 84,
            'authorization' => 'Bearer <access token>'
        }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
        '_method' => 'PUT',
        '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
    }, 'HTTP::Request' )
}, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

What should I try changing on the Perl side to make BigQuery respond to me like it does to `bq`?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your PUT headers have colons in front of them, where the Python does not:

```
':Content-Length' => '84',
':Content-Range' => '0-83/84',
```

Comment: Those colons do not affect my results either way.  Having them there tells HTTP::Headers to not canonicalize capitalization of headers.  I was hoping that forcing the same capitalization as Python would help, but it did not.

That said, if BigQuery violates http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt by making headers case sensitive, then I will need a list of what capitalizations are needed, where.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something malformed in the multipart upload request. The error "Invalid Upload Request" is in response to attempting to split the data payload out of the multipart mime message. Your logging doesn't include details on the body of the requests, so we can't side-by-side compare them for unexpected differences.

To make sure that the problem is the multipart upload, you could try a load request that loads data from Google Storage rather than including the data in the request payload itself. This would verify that the perl api request path is working for you.

FYI: There is an alpha Perl Google Apis client that might help you out. I haven't tried it and don't know whether it's actively in development or not, but you might find some useful hints there. Check out https://code.google.com/p/google-api-perl-client/

Comment: The body in Perl is byte for byte the same as the contents of `body` inside of the `request` method of `httplib2` in the Python version.  Are you suggesting that Python looks at the fact it is a post, and alters that body before it reaches your service?

Comment: I will look at that client.  At a glance it is alpha, and only recently had any support for uploads added.  But it is worth trying.